# inequalities involving cardinalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I really have no clue how to solve the next question. please help.

Let a,b,c be cardinalities of sets A,B,C.

Prove or disprove:

a. if $a \leq b$ and $a\cdot{c}\neq0$, then $c^a \leq c^b$.

b. if $a<b$, then $a\cdot{c}<b\cdot{c}$.

Thanks!

Comment: cardinalities are number of element in set right?

Comment: Regarding b., the same formula is true for positive natural numbers, but not for $c=0$ or for 'infinite' numbers. Translate this into cardinalities.

Comment: @Galc is that  what you wanted?

Comment: dato, your'e right - cardinality is the number of elements in set. Git, unfortunately, I didn't understand your comment clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally as i know cardinal can't be negative number or irrational or rational ,so we have  $a,b,c$ belongs to non negative  whole numbers.
if $a<b$  clearly $c^a<c^b$  for example  $c=4$ and $a=2$ and  $b=3$  then we know that  $16<64$,but according to this

http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC5/docpspdf/infinity.pdf

second equation is not correct if cardinal of $C$ is equal to zero or   $C$ is empthy space